Next JS app built using output: 'export' not rendered properly
The Next JS app built using output: 'export' not rendering the CSS properly.
To Reproduce

Create new nextjs app
Update next config to output as static site
Open the outputted page from out folder

Current Output

Expected Output

Above output is when app run using dev mode
Tried including the CSS link directly in index.html of generated output but still it is not working

Friend, the issue is that you are using Tailwind CSS, but it isn't being called when you open your static HTML file. If you run the file on a server, such as GitHub Pages, the CSS will be applied to your code.
Cheers.
